# Why does the Java equals(Object O) method not have a variant which can take a specific object type (e.g. String, Integer, etc) as input?

Tags: java, generics, equality, string-comparison, method-signature

I come across problems where I need to compare two strings (or any other object ) for equality/non-equality using Java language. 
There are two methods on String Object very useful for this purpose viz. `compareTo(Object O)`, which returns a integer result of comparison while other `equals(Object o)`, which returns a boolean. 
My question is while there is a variant for `compareTo()` which takes a specific String as input instead of an generic Object, why there is no such variant for `equals()` ?
One issue that I often come across is when I invoke equals method on an object and passes generic object as an argument it doesn't throw any compile error.
Consider the code snippet below (this is not a real life example but I have written to just make my point clear).

```
String testStr = new String("1");
Integer testInt = new Integer(1);

testStr.compareTo(testInt.toString()); // compiles
testStr.equals(testInt.toString());    // compiles

testStr.equals(testInt);               // compiles and will be always false 
testStr.compareTo(testInt);            // doesn't compile
```

Comment: You can create an equals(T obj) but if you pass something other than an object of type T, it would call the inherited equals(Object obj), so how would that help you?

Comment: I guess the equals(T obj) method that you are talking about is part of external library, isn't it?

Comment: No, I mean if you implement it in a generic class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `equals()` is declared in `Object` and `compareTo(T foo)` is defined in `Comparable<T>`.

Before generics the issue was the same with `Comparable`, `compareTo` taking an Object argument, but since there's no "`Equalable`" interface there was no place to stick the generic parameter.

Comment: Don't you mean [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html)?

Comment: You say Equivalence, I say "Equalable" ;)

Comment: I think he was referring to the class, not the vocabulary :p

Comment: @traveh Well it's a Guava class. It won't change difference between `equals()` and `compareTo()`.

Comment: Indeed... I was just clarifying :)